# Grails2.4.3: export to pdf/excel using JQGrid

Tags: grails, jqgrid, export, mvcjqgrid, grails-2.4

Currently I'm working on Grails2.4.3 and not able to find a workaround that how I could export my JQGrid data which is in grails(.gsp) into excel/pdf and in other formats.

Comment: Why did you not try grails export plugin??

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying but not getting how to join grails and Jqgrid.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code what you tried so far?

Comment: jQuery(tableId).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', navigationId, {

                caption: "Export to Excel",

                onClickButton: function () {
                 //window.open ("exportToPdf_Excel");
                    jQuery(tableId).jqGrid('excelExport', { url: 'exportToPdf_Excel' });

                }

            });